# Is there a way to keep tooltip open if hovering over tooltip container (content) in ngx bootstrap?

Tags: angular, typescript, tooltip, ngx-bootstrap

I want to keep tooltip open if hover over the tooltip container(content). how I can achieve it in angular ngx-bootstrap ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [tooltipFadeDuration] and you can define fade duration. Default is 150 and you can try and set it to higher value.

You may need to add it as a directive, so it would be like [tooltipFadeDuration]="500". The higher the number, the more time it will take to fade.

This is in the official documentation:
https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/tooltip

Comment: I want to do it on mouseover and mouseout only. but in case i will hover over tooltip container within certain time (delay time for tooltip to get destroyed) the tooltip should not disappear.

Comment: @ranjeetkumar I have revised the answer